# is multiprocessing manager registered type's argument copied?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to convert my class so other processes have access to it.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time


class SharedType:
    def __init__(self, custom_arg):
        self.count = 0
        self.custom_arg = custom_arg
        self.builtin_arg = []

    def accum(self):
        self.count += 1

    def get_count(self):
        return self.count

    def get_custom_arg(self):
        return self.custom_arg

    def get_builtin_arg(self):
        return self.builtin_arg


class CustomArg:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = []

    def append(self, i):
        self.v.append(i)


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass


MyManager.register('SharedType', SharedType)


def count(obj, uid):
    print(uid, 'start')
    # record uid
    obj.get_custom_arg().append(uid)
    obj.get_builtin_arg().append(uid)
    # do some work
    for _ in range(100_000):
        obj.accum()
    return id


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('run single process')
    st = time.time()
    c = 0
    for _ in range(10):
        for __ in range(100_000):
            c += 1
    print(c, f'elapse: {time.time() - st}')
    print()

    print('run multi process')
    st = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool()
    with MyManager() as manager:
        shared_obj = manager.SharedType(CustomArg())
        # run
        ps = [pool.apply_async(count, args=(shared_obj, i)) for i in range(10)]
        print('waiting...')
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(shared_obj.get_count(), f'elapse: {time.time() - st}')
        print(shared_obj.get_custom_arg().v, shared_obj.get_builtin_arg())
```

result is as follows:

```py
run single process
1000000 elapse: 0.14413094520568848

run multi process
waiting...
0 start
1 start
2 start
4 start
5 start
3 start
7 start
8 start
6 start
9 start
1000000 elapse: 36.199955463409424
[] []
```

What I expected was to see `shared_obj`'s attributes remain shared as `shared_obj.count` does, rather being copied into processes' own memories. So is there a way to share whole attributes including complex ones? Or is such an idea total nonsense? 
And additionally, what is the overhead making multiprocessing so slow in above case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what `multiprocessing` sometimes tries to pretend, you cannot have an object exist in two processes at the same time in Python, at all.

---

In your code, the manager is associated with a server process, and the `SharedType` instance lives in that server process. The master's `shared_obj` is a proxy object that communicates with the server process for method calls. When you pass `shared_obj` to `pool.apply_async`, the workers also get proxies, created by pickling the master's proxy and unpickling the pickle in the worker.

When you call a method on such a proxy, all arguments are pickled, the pickled representations are sent over inter-process communication to the server, and the server unpickles them to construct new objects. The server then calls the method on the `SharedType` instance, pickles the return value, and sends the pickled data back to the process that requested the method call, which unpickles the pickle to construct its own copy of the method return value.

(All this pickling and unpickling and inter-process communication is *really* slow, which is why multiprocessing slowed your code down so much. multiprocessing is *really slow*.)

---

`count` isn't actually any more shared than the other attributes here. The difference is that you updated `count` through the proxy's `accum` method, which communicates with the server process and updates the `count` in the server's `SharedType` instance, but you tried to update `custom_arg` and `builtin_arg` by calling methods on *copies* returned by a proxy's `get_custom_arg` and `get_builtin_arg` methods. Modifying a copy does not notify the server of changes or do anything to the `SharedType` instance living in the server process.

---

If you want to be able to operate on the return value of `get_custom_arg` and `get_builtin_arg` and have that affect the master objects living in the server process, the proxy's `get_custom_arg` and `get_builtin_arg` have to return proxies too. That means you'll have to register `list` and `CustomArg`, and add methods to `CustomArg` to read its data without accessing `v` directly. I think you might also have to create `builtin_arg` and `custom_arg` through the manager, or use `_method_to_typeid_` to get the SharedType's proxy to return proxies from `get_builtin_arg` and `get_custom_arg` - I haven't managed to work out all the bugs in my own attempt, so I'm not sure of the full details.

---

Unrelated issue: managers don't eliminate the need for synchronization. If you're going to mutate shared objects like this, you need to use a lock to prevent race conditions.

Comment: I'm understanding a bit more now. What I'm seeking through this test code is to develop a design that allows other process use and update some of the (ambiguous) server side objects' attributes. The application I'm working on generally follows OOP and is already quite big. While registering all classes and maintain an object in the server process is technically possible, It feels like impractical as creating new class and setting getting arguments will always go through proxies.

Comment: Is there general solution or design patter that can be used in such a scenario where occasionally works, that references server-side object, attributes, is passed to another process and that process would do CPU intensive calculation and update server-side attribute with the result? without much hassling?

Comment: @김기영: I don't know of a good solution for that.